# Cython mapping c++ data structures

Tags: c++, python, wrapper, cython

I'm using cython to wrap my C++ class:

`Foo.h`

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::map<int,int > myMap;
    std::vector<int> myVector;
public:
    // An example of internal structures initialization
    Foo()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
             myVector.push_back(i);
             myMap[i]=i*i;
        }
    }
    std::map<int,int> getMyMap()
    {
        return myMap;
    }
    std::vector<int> getMyVector()
    {
        return myVector;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is some way to get the `std::map` as python `dict` and the std::vector as python `list` without explicitly creating (and thus wasting memory) copies of such structures.

A temptative implementation for the std::vector is the following:

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
    Foo()
    vector[int]  getMyVector()


cdef class pyFoo:
cdef Foo *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
def __cinit__(self):
    self.thisptr = new Foo()

def getMyVector(self):
    cdef vector[int] aa
    cdef int N
    b= []
    aa = self.thisptr.getMyVector()
    N=aa.size()
    for i in range(N):
        b.append(aa[i])
    return b;
```

But this clearly must store two structures containing the same data. I'm wondering if there is a way to map from c++ to list with cython or should I use boost::python?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good reason to convert the vector to a python list, which is using it as a regular list in python code. However, you can wrap the vector and add a getter function. You will save some memory indeed, but I think that would be much less efficient, as you'll have to call the function each time to get a value and you won't be able to use it in any python expressions as you would a python list.

Comment: Ok, the only problem I'm facing is dealing with custom-type for the vector. In this case we use `vector<int>` but the cython compiler isn't able to cope with, for example `vector<Foo*>` where `Foo` is one of my classes.

Comment: Indeed for what you are asking python list and dict should be best suited. As for Foo* - you can get around this by using uintptr_t type instead of Foo* and cast back to Foo* in cdef methods.